# TPM, Openconnect. The requested PKCS #11 object is not available

Tags: tpm, openconnect

I have a problem with openconnect VPN using TPM and certificate.

```
Using certificate file /etc/pki/XXXX/XXXXX.crt
Error importing PKCS#11 URL pkcs11:model=SLB9670;manufacturer=Infineon;serial=0000000000000000;token=XXXXX-TPM2-TOKEN;id=%30%32;object=XXXXX-RSA2048-keypair;type=private: The requested PKCS #11 object is not available
Loading certificate failed. Aborting.
Failed to open HTTPS connection to YYYYY.com
```

What can I do to find the root cause?